# div with horizontal list

Tags: html, css

I want to create a "footer" like on the first column in design on this page -> https://dribbble.com/shots/2262761-Mobile-Blog-App-Interface/attachments/424147

I've a problem with displaying the horizontal list, i cant figure out why this dots are at the bottom of the div.

I want to make one big div for the whole "footer" and then 3 divs like this:
1) first div with text CLOSE

2) second div with 4 dots and

3) last div with the some icon from Font Awesome.

What i am doing wrong with displaying this 4dots? Should I try different way with displaying than unordered list?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="footer-text">CLOSE</div>
<ul class="dots">
<li>.</li>
<li class="dot">.</li>
<li class="dot">.</li>
<li class="dot">.</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer-text {
float:left;
display:inline-block;
background-color: white;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 5px;
}
.dots{
background-color: white;
margin-top:0px;
float:left; 
padding-top: 0px;
padding-left:0px;

}

li {
display:inline;
font-size: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q7cyu7sa/2/ -> my pseudocode

Comment: can you share your code to help you better

Comment: Not sure what you want. These 4 dots seems like change with pages, but what you said seems like 'static' 4 dots. If dots change with pages, this would use javascript

Comment: i want only to code in codepen this design from dribble.

Comment: post the code you tried to create this with

Comment: this dots should be static, i want to make it only in HTML&CSS

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q7cyu7sa/7/

Comment: i just forget about add the link with my pseudocode

Answer (score 2):

you can use `display: flex` for the footer area and a `div` with list of `span` for the dots. The spans are already displayed inline and you just need to centralize the content.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">

  <div class="image">
    Image
  </div>

  <div class="footer">  
    <div>
      Close
    </div>

    <div class="dots">
      <span>.</span>
      <span>.</span>
      <span>.</span>
      <span>.</span>      
    </div>

    <div>
      Comments
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

  .item .image {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .item .footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: flex;
  }

    .item .footer > div{
      flex: 1;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      background-color: #eee;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .item .footer .dots {
      text-align: center;
    }

      .item .footer .dots > span {
        font-size: 50px;
        line-height: 0px;
      }
```

**PREVIEW:**

[image: Preview]

Comment: yeah this divison is nice, but when i try to put the unordered list inside to make this dots i encounter problems

Comment: I think I got the issue @amazintesla. You can use a div with spans for the dots section and apply`text-align:center`. The spans are displayed inline and you just need to centralize the content. You can see my changes in the code above.

Comment: yeah its quite tricky task to do it with list. I definietely have to read about 'flexbox'.

Answer (score 2):

As bocanegra has said, you could use display:flex; on the footer container, and flex-grow to adjust the sizes which would be useful for sizing the tap areas on the interactive elements.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.navigation {
  text-align: center;
}
.comment {
  text-align: right;
}
```

It's also worth noting you can order flex elements in CSS, which allows you to order the HTML sensibly.

Here is an example. Remove the first comment in the CSS to view a border for a better idea on sizing.
https://codepen.io/fraig/pen/PKPNGK

Comment: yeah thanks, it's looks definitely closer to the pattern  :D

Answer (score 0):

Edited your code with bootstrap simple fix:

https://plnkr.co/edit/LQSbZ0B6Upwf3UETfudm?p=preview

I think the guy above did all the work anyways

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="center one col-xs-4">
      <h2>CLOSE</h2>
    </div>
      <div class="center one col-xs-4">
      <ul>
        <li><a>.</a></li>
         <li><a>.</a></li>
          <li><a>.</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <div class="center one col-xs-4">
      <h2>IMAGE</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. div and ul are display:block by default. In some cases is better to
   use span, which is display:inline, to avoid additional coding.
2. float left or right will take the element out of the parent border
   and position, and that's why you saw the "ul" in the second line,
   even if used the display:inline-block.

https://jsfiddle.net/q7cyu7sa/9/

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
    <span class="footer-text">CLOSE</span>
    <ul class="dots">
        <li>.</li>
        <li>.</li>
        <li>.</li>
        <li>.</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
  background-color:white;
 }
.footer-text {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 5px;
  margin:0;
}    
.dots {
  display:inline;
  margin:0 10px;
  }      
li {
  display:inline;
  font-size: 50px; line-height:20px;
}    
li:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  color: lightgray;
}
```

**ANOTHER WAY** SIMPLYFIED: https://jsfiddle.net/q7cyu7sa/12/

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
    <span class="footer-text">CLOSE</span>
    <dots>.</dots>
    <dots>.</dots>
    <dots>.</dots>
    <dots>.</dots>
    <dots>.</dots>         
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
  background-color:white;
 }

.footer-text {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 5px;
  margin:0;
}

dots {
  font-size: 50px; 
  line-height:20px;
  margin:0;
  color:black;
  }
dots:nth-of-type(n+2){
    color: lightgray;
  }
```

Comment: You can use flexbox also, but learb how to use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: so you suggest that it is better to use span than list in this case?

Comment: I meant about using span instead of div. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: so it is possible to make list inside span ? :D   or you mean that each dot should inside span?

Comment: No. You've used the word "close" in a div and then you've made it display:inline-block, instead of using only <span>Close</span>. This is what I meant.  You wrote the list ok, I've only changed added :nth-of-type for color, instead of putting the class "gray" for each of the gray dots :)

Comment: Instead of list, you can use span, but create the css for it. I'try to make some fiddle, wait.